# Onetoonefield sobre User, sigo sin comprederlo y hacerlo funcionar

Tags: python, django

Después de seguir, leer y copiar varios ejemplos de dicho proceso, sigue sin funcionar mi intento de programa. Lo único que pretendo es crear un modelo extendido de la clase User (¿se dice así?). También pretendo que el email sea la clave principal en lugar del username, he visto que se puede hacer con la librería allauth, pero eso lo dejo para mas adelante. Al ser aprendiz, no comprendo muy bien los ejemplos, problemas y soluciones que he encontrado como el mío.
El problema actual es que al registrar un usuario nuevo me manda esto:

(1048, "Column 'user_id' cannot be null")

es un campo está la tabla User (¿customer_id?) y que estará unido a la tabla navegante y no sé exactamente como enlazarlo al registrar un usuario/navegante nuevo en la clase VRegistro. Como he dicho he visto ejemplos y soluciones (aquí), pero no consigo trasladarlo. Por favor, podéis ayudarme? Gracias.

Navegantes-->models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from paises.models import pais

# Create your models here.

class User (AbstractUser):
    customer_id = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return (self.customer_id)

class Navegante (models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='navegante')
    cif_nif = models.CharField(max_length=20,blank=True)
    pais = models.ForeignKey(pais,models.SET_NULL,blank=True,null=True)
    tlf1 = models.CharField(max_length=10,blank=True)
    tlf2 = models.CharField(max_length=10,blank=True)
    denominacion = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True)
    contacto = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True)
    inicio_comunicacion = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    fin_comunicacion = models.DateTimeField(null=True,blank=True)

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return (self.user.email)

def create_user_navegante(sender,instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Navegante.objects.create(user=instance)

def save_user_navegante(sender,instance, **kwargs):
    instance.navegante.save()

# save created profil
post_save.connect(create_user_navegante,sender=User)
post_save.connect(save_user_navegante,sender=User)
```

Navegantes-->forms.py

```
from django import forms
from navegantes.models import Navegante
from django.db import models
#from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Navegante_class (forms.ModelForm):
    username = forms.EmailField()
    password1 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    password2 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    class Meta:
        model = Navegante
        #fields = '__all__'
        fields = ['username']
```

Navegantes-->views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .forms import Navegante_class
from django.views.generic import View
from django.contrib.auth import login,logout,authenticate
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm,UserCreationForm

# Create your views here.
class VRegistro(View):
    def registro (request):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = Navegante_class(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():                
                username = form.save()
                login(request,username)
                return redirect ("Inicio")
            else:
                if form.errors:
                    for key, values in form.errors.as_data().items():
                        if key == 'username':
                            messages.info(request, 'Correo electrónico ya existente.')
                            break
                        else:
                            for error_value in values:
                                messages.info(request, '%s' % (error_value.message))                    
            context = {'form' : form } 
            return render(request,'navegantes/registro.html',context)                   
        else:
            form = Navegante_class()
            context = {'form' : form }
            return render(request,'navegantes/registro.html',context)
```

Navegantes-->urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import acceder,cerrar_sesion,VRegistro


urlpatterns = [     
    path('registro/', VRegistro.registro,name = "Registro"),    
    path('acceder', acceder,name = "Acceder"),    
    path('cerrar_sesion', cerrar_sesion,name = "cerrar_sesion"),
]
```

Estos son los peis, de la aplicación.
Gracias anticipadas.

Answer (score 0):

veo que estas usando el form de navegante, pero no has creado el form de usuario.

Por lo tanto cuando hacer form.save() el usuario no existe aun. De ahí el error (1048, "Column 'user_id' cannot be null")

Puedes crear otro form para el usuario (form2) y pasarlo al contexto

```
class UsuarioForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2')

class PerfilForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Perfil
        fields = ('campo1', 'campo2', 'usuario')

def registro(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        usuario_form = UsuarioForm(request.POST)
        perfil_form = PerfilForm(request.POST)
        if usuario_form.is_valid() and perfil_form.is_valid():
            user = usuario_form.save(commit=False)
            user.save()
            perfil = perfil_form.save(commit=False)
            perfil.usuario = user
            perfil.save()
            return redirect('registro_exitoso')
    else:
        usuario_form = UsuarioForm()
        perfil_form = PerfilForm()
    return render(request, 'registro.html', {'usuario_form': usuario_form, 'perfil_form': perfil_form})
```

Comment: Te agradezco enormemente la respuesta. Analizando ..........   ...........